# Constraint Layout put view below if there is not enough space horizontally

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Is anyone aware of how to position the buttons vertically if the button text is too long inside of the xml?

I want the buttons to be positioned horizontally if they fit, if one of the buttons has to hyphenate, then I would like to avoid that by positioning the buttons below each other. Is there a way to do it inside of the XML only?

Thanks!

[image: Layout where button text is too long]

[image: Expected behavior]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_header"
        style="@style/TitleTextAppearance.WithPrimaryBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/header_enter_startcode" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_background_with_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_status"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pls_enter_startcode"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_default"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_startcode"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/grid_2"
            app:helperText="@string/example_startcode"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_status">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/tiet_startcode"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/gl_middle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_continue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_2"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_2"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_2"
            android:text="@string/btn_continue"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gl_middle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_startcode" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
            style="?materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_2"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_2"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_2"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gl_middle"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_startcode" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you checked Flow helper of constraint layout v2.0? https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow

Answer (score 1):

You can put the elements in a Flow helper and configure it to automatically wrap. Remove the unnecessary constraints from btn_continue and btn_cancel

```
        <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
            android:id="@+id/flow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_2"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_2"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_2"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="btn_continue,btn_cancel"
            app:flow_horizontalGap="@dimen/grid_2"
            app:flow_horizontalStyle="spread"
            app:flow_wrapMode="aligned"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_startcode" />
   
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_continue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_continue"/>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
            style="?materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this is a very elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by creating a custom view which extends ConstraintLayout Flow. (Kudos @guglhupf for suggestion).
This should also adapt to when Foldable device is being folded.

**Kotlin**

```kotlin
    import android.content.Context
    import android.util.AttributeSet
    import android.util.Log
    import android.view.View
    import android.widget.Button
    import androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
    import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    import androidx.core.view.allViews
    import androidx.core.view.updateLayoutParams
    
    internal class FlexLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : Flow(context, attrs) {
    
        override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
            makeChildrenMatchParentIfTheyArePositionedVertically()
        }
    
        private fun makeChildrenMatchParentIfTheyArePositionedVertically() {
            allViews.forEach { flexLayoutCandidate ->
                (flexLayoutCandidate as? FlexLayout)?.let { flexLayout ->
                    val mutableMapOfYCoordinatesAndView = mutableMapOf<View, Int>()
    
                    //Check all the Id's that Flow layout is referencing and store them in a map
                    flexLayout.referencedIds.forEach { referenceId ->
                        val foundView = rootView.findViewById<View>(referenceId)
                        if (foundView != null) {
                            val locationOnScreen = IntArray(size = 2)
                            foundView.getLocationOnScreen(locationOnScreen)
    
                            Log.d("FlexLayout", "Name ${(foundView as? Button)?.text}")
                            Log.d("FlexLayout", "Location on screen: x = ${locationOnScreen[0]} y = ${locationOnScreen[1]}")
    
                            mutableMapOfYCoordinatesAndView[foundView] = locationOnScreen[1]
                        }
                    }
                    var previousMapEntry: Map.Entry<View, Int>? = null
                    mutableMapOfYCoordinatesAndView.forEach loopToCompareWhetherTheYCoordinatesAreDifferent@{
                        val currentMapEntry = it
                        if (previousMapEntry == null) {
                            previousMapEntry = currentMapEntry
                            return@loopToCompareWhetherTheYCoordinatesAreDifferent
                        }
                        //Check if Flow layout decided to put the view on the next line
                        if (previousMapEntry?.value != currentMapEntry.value) {
                            previousMapEntry?.key?.updateLayoutParams<ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams> {
                                width = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                            }
                            currentMapEntry.key.updateLayoutParams<ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams> {
                                width = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                            }
                        }
                        previousMapEntry = currentMapEntry
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**XML**

```
    <company.name.customview.FlexLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_between_view_blocks"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="btn_dialog_negative, btn_dialog_positive"
        app:flow_horizontalGap="@dimen/space_between_two_buttons"
        app:flow_horizontalStyle="spread_inside"
        app:flow_verticalGap="@dimen/space_between_two_buttons"
        app:flow_wrapMode="aligned"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tv_dialog_body"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_dialog_body"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_dialog_body" />
```